# OnClickListener RecyclerView List of buttons

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, onclicklistener, buttonclick

I have a RecyclerView and each item is a button. Each button will call the same activity by passing a different parameter to this activity.

I tried many solutions found on the web but none of them had worked for me.

Here is my adapter :

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

import java.util.List;

public class FormAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<FormAdapter.FormViewHolder> {

    private List<Form> forms;
    private int rowLayout;
    private Context context;


    public class FormViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        LinearLayout formsLayout;
        Button form;

        public FormViewHolder(View v) {
            super(v);

            formsLayout = (LinearLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.forms_layout);
            form = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.formButton);

        }

    }

    public FormAdapter(List<Form> forms, int rowLayout, Context context) {
        this.forms = forms;
        this.rowLayout = rowLayout;
        this.context = context;
    }



    @Override
    public FormAdapter.FormViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(rowLayout, parent, false);
        return new FormViewHolder(view);
    }


    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(FormViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        holder.form.setText(forms.get(position).getSubject());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return forms.size();
    }

}
```

A form is represented by the following class :

```
public class Form {

    private final String subject;
    private final int idForm;

    public Form(String subject,int idForm)
    {
        this.idForm=idForm;
        this.subject=subject;
    }

    public String getSubject()
    {
        return subject;
    }

    public int getIdForm()
    {
        return idForm;
    }

}
```

And here is my MainActivity :

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.Log;

import java.util.List;
import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.Callback;
import retrofit2.Response;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    private final static int idCreator = 1;
    private FormAdapter formAdapter;
    private List<Form> forms;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        setTitle("Main activity");

        final RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerViewForm);

        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

        Formable formService =
                ApiClient.getClient().create(Formable.class);

        Call<List<Form>> call = formService.getForms(idCreator);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<List<Form>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<Form>> call, Response<List<Form>> response) {
                forms = response.body();
                formAdapter=new FormAdapter(forms, R.layout.one_form, getApplicationContext());
                recyclerView.setAdapter(formAdapter);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<List<Form>> call, Throwable t) {
                // Log error here since request failed
                Log.e(TAG, t.toString());
            }
        });

    }
}
```

I have my buttons on screen but I don't understand how to make them call the activity "QuestionsActivity" with a parameter "idForm" that I know.

Here is the MainActivity when I run the app

[image]

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: First of all get all button position using from setonclicklistner after this position click to send different parameter pass..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get item data by following way when you click on recyclerview item:

Create Interface in your adapter and use it in your activity:

```
private OnItemClickListener mListener;
public interface OnItemClickListener {
    public void onItemClick(View view, int position);
}
```

Now Your code look like below:

**FormAdapter.java**

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

import java.util.List;

    public class FormAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<FormAdapter.FormViewHolder> {

        private List<Form> forms;
        private int rowLayout;
        private Context context;

        private OnItemClickListener mListener;
        public interface OnItemClickListener {
            public void onItemClick(View view, int position);
        }

        public class FormViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

            LinearLayout formsLayout;
            Button form;

            public FormViewHolder(View v) {
                super(v);

                formsLayout = (LinearLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.forms_layout);
                form = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.formButton);

            }

        }

        public FormAdapter(List<Form> forms, int rowLayout, Context context) {
            this.forms = forms;
            this.rowLayout = rowLayout;
            this.context = context;
        }



        @Override
        public FormAdapter.FormViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(rowLayout, parent, false);
            return new FormViewHolder(view);
        }


        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(FormViewHolder holder, final int position) {
            holder.form.setText(forms.get(position).getSubject());
            holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    if(mListener!=null)
                    {
                        mListener.onItemClick(view,position);
                    }
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return forms.size();
        }


        public void setOnItemClick(OnItemClickListener listener)
        {
            this.mListener=listener;
        }

    }
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;

import com.newstory.android.R;
import com.newstory.android.activity.FormAdapter;

import java.util.List;
import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.Callback;
import retrofit2.Response;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    private final static int idCreator = 1;
    private FormAdapter formAdapter;
    private List<Form> forms;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        setTitle("Main activity");

        final RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerViewForm);

        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

        Formable formService =
                ApiClient.getClient().create(Formable.class);

        Call<List<Form>> call = formService.getForms(idCreator);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<List<Form>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<Form>> call, Response<List<Form>> response) {
                forms = response.body();
                formAdapter=new FormAdapter(forms, R.layout.one_form, getApplicationContext());
                recyclerView.setAdapter(formAdapter);
                setOnItemListener();
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<List<Form>> call, Throwable t) {
                // Log error here since request failed
                Log.e(TAG, t.toString());
            }
        });

    }

    public void setOnItemListener(){
        if(formAdapter!=null)
        {
            formAdapter.setOnItemClick(new FormAdapter.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {
                    Form clickedForm=forms.get(position);
                    // You can call QuestionsActivity here 
                    //Now you can access [Form] data
                    Log.d("getIdForm->",String.valueOf(clickedForm.getIdForm()))
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

I hope it's helps you.

Comment: I used this code but the buttons don't start the activity. I don't know why but if I click many times on the buttons the activity starts one time on 20...

Comment: Change `itemview` onclick to `button` onclick.
And try to add `focusableInTouchMode="true"` in your item button xml code.

Comment: Welcome. glade to know it's helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Do this way :

```
 form.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // do something when the form is clicked
                 context.startActivity(new Intent(context, YourActivity.class)
                                      .putExtra("idForm", someValue));
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

In your adapter's `onBindViewHolder` method, assign a click listener to the button view element, so it would look something like this:

```
 @Override
public void onBindViewHolder(FormViewHolder holder, final int position {
    holder.form.setText(forms.get(position).getSubject());
    holder.form.setOnClickListener(v -> {
        startQuestionsWithId(forms.get(position).getIdForm);
    });
}
```

And then, your `startQuestionsWithId`method would typically be like:

```
private void startQuestionsWithId(int idForm) {
 Intent intent = new Intent(context, QuestionsActivity.class);
 intent.putExtra("id_form", idForm);
 context.startActivity(intent); 
}
```

Comment: When I click the buttons, the activity doesn't start. In fact nothing happens

Comment: if the project compiles fine, and nothing happens when you click the button (not even a runtime exception is thrown), then most likely the click listener is not properly assigned to the button. To ensure it is, I'd go about just printing a log statement initially as to what to do in the click listener handler and see if it's actually logging what you want. If that works, then the  `startQuestionsWithId` has to work or throw a runtime exception when called. Let me know if you're still trying to get it work with this method.